# magento 2 : Product listing default sorting order based on attributes

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, sorting, product-sorting

i have add sort by attributes to products say like below one.

```
"Publish date"
"Product Name"
"Price"
```

Now i want to change sort order based on default attributes. For eg 
1: Publish date -> Descending order
2: Product Name -> Ascending order
3: Price -> Ascending order

I tried below xml code in category layout xml update, but by adding it my product are sorted in descending order for all attributes, can i define sort order based on attributes in below code

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection">
            <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```